# Is there a way to be notified by email whenever there is a new item on Google Reader?

Tags: email, rss, google-reader, notifications, rss-reader

I want be notified from Google Reader via email each time a new item shows up in one of my rss feeds. Is that possible?

Comment: Really? You want that much email? If I did that my email alerts would be going off like a pachinko machine, and I only subscribe to a couple dozen feeds.

Comment: Yes, I really want do that, I suppose that I just have feeds that I really need read ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This IFTTT recipe](https://ifttt.com/recipes/42561) gets you most of the way there. You just need to tag all of the feeds from which you want this email alert with a particular tag. (Since feeds can have multiple tags, you could tag all of them if you want.)

- **Google Reader** channel, *New item tagged* trigger
- **Gmail** channel, *send an email* action

For every new item in Google Reader with a specific tag, sends an email message from your Gmail account to an address you have specified.